# How to connect Node.js in Docker container to Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:carbon
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
COPY *.card ./
RUN npm install
RUN ./node_modules/.bin/composer card import --file admin@biznetwork.card --card admin@biznetwork
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

connection.js used to create admin@biznetwork.card
(I replaced "://localhost:port" with the running container names)
[image]

```
{  
    "name":"hlfv1",
    "x-type":"hlfv1",
    "x-commitTimeout":300,
    "version":"1.0.0",
    "client":{  
       "organization":"Org1",
       "connection":{  
          "timeout":{  
             "peer":{  
                "endorser":"300",
                "eventHub":"300",
                "eventReg":"300"
             },
             "orderer":"300"
          }
       }
    },
    "channels":{  
       "composerchannel":{  
          "orderers":[  
             "orderer.example.com"
          ],
          "peers":{  
             "peer0.org1.example.com":{  

             }
          }
       }
    },
    "organizations":{  
       "Org1":{  
          "mspid":"Org1MSP",
          "peers":[  
             "peer0.org1.example.com"
          ],
          "certificateAuthorities":[  
             "ca.org1.example.com"
          ]
       }
    },
    "orderers":{  
       "orderer.example.com":{  
          "url":"grpc://orderer.example.com:7050"
       }
    },
    "peers":{  
       "peer0.org1.example.com":{  
          "url":"grpc://peer0.org1.example.com:7051",
          "eventUrl":"grpc://peer0.org1.example.com:7053"
       }
    },
    "certificateAuthorities":{  
       "ca.org1.example.com":{  
          "url":"http://ca.org1.example.com:7054",
          "caName":"ca.org1.example.com"
       }
    }
 }
```

Node.js app cannot connect and gets error:

```
(node:17) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Error trying to ping. Error: 2 UNKNOWN: error executing chaincode: transaction returned with failure: Error: The current identity, with the name 'admin' and the identifier 'fcb2071b5df74a16b4b93b14bff69af15c1104df6465a23ae4ec3473cc663d71', has not been registered
```

Feel like I may be doing something wrong with the card because

```
RUN ./node_modules/.bin/composer card import --file admin@biznetwork.card --card admin@biznetwork
RUN ./node_modules/.bin/composer network ping --card admin@biznetwork
```

doesn't connect.

Comment: Does `./node_modules/.bin/composer card import --file admin@biznetwork.card --card admin@biznetwork` work on the local system (on Docker host)?

Comment: Yes it does. That import succeeds, but the ping after it fails. I am unsure of the proper to way to get the cards typically in `~/.composer/cards` so they can be found by the Node.js app running inside the container.

Comment: I think my issue is in `connection.json` I am not sure what `localhost` should be changed to in order to point to the Hyperledger Fabric containers within the same docker network.

Comment: You can try the name of the container itself if you are using a user-defined network (I don't know if this works with the default network, correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: Is `~/.composer/cards` a directory on your Docker host? If yes then you can use volume (-v) to map `~/.composer/cards` (which is on your Docker host) to `~/.composer/cards` (which you can create in Docker container).

Comment: That was it! I had to do `docker run -v ~/.composer:/root/.composer ...` Thank you for teaching me about `-v`!

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do I find the IP address of my Docker Host to use in connection.json instead of the container name?

Comment: The container that you create will be having a different IP address that the Docker host, like if the Docker Host's IP is `172.17.0.1` (`172.17.0.0/16`) then the containers will have the IP address of `172.17.0.2` and onwards.

But if you want to get the IP address of the Docker host then you can run 
`ip a s` 
and check for `docker0: <some entry>`, this will give you Docker host's IP address(`docker0` is the default bridge which gets created when you install Docker.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to map `~/.composer/cards` of your Docker host to `~/.composer/cards` of your container.